# React-Stripe-JS: how to add border styling to a form?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am working with `react-stripe-js` and am working on styling card elements. I am having trouble adding border styling to the styles I created. I have the code below in my CheckoutForm, I attempted to add a colored border for example. Instead of getting any border all I get are borderless inputs.[image]

**CheckoutForm.js**
...

```
const ELEMENT_OPTIONS = {
  iconStyle: "solid",
  hidePostalCode: true,
  style: {
    base: {
      border: '2px solid red',//TRIED THIS**************************
      iconColor: "rgb(240, 57, 122)",
      color: "rgb(240, 57, 122)",
      fontSize: "16px",
      fontFamily: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: "antialiased",
      "::placeholder": {
        color: "#CFD7DF"
      }
    },
    invalid: {
      color: "#e5424d",
      ":focus": {
        color: "#303238"
      }
    }
  }
};
...

<form onSubmit={this.SaveCard}>
          <div className="split-form">
            <label htmlFor="cardNumber">Card Number</label>
            <CardNumberElement
              id="cardNumber"
              options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
            />
            <label htmlFor="expiry">Card Expiration</label>
            <CardExpiryElement
              id="expiry"
              options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="split-form">
            <label htmlFor="cvc">CVC</label>
            <CardCvcElement
              id="cvc"
              options={ELEMENT_OPTIONS}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
            Save Card
          </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: no sirve para nada el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

I did it by surrounding each CardElement by div and adding my style to the parent div:

```
<div style={{ margin: '10px 0 10px', border: 'solid' }}>
    <CardNumberElement
      options={options}
      onReady={() => {
        console.log("CardNumberElement [ready]");
      }}
      onChange={event => {
        // console.log("CardNumberElement [change]", event);
      }}
      onBlur={() => {
        console.log("CardNumberElement [blur]");
      }}
      onFocus={() => {
        console.log("CardNumberElement [focus]");
      }}
    />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding it as part of the (internal) Elements styling, you'll want to style the `<Card*Element>`s directly instead, as you would any other element.